# Why is my cookie not being saved on Safari but being saved on Chrome?

Tags: express, cookies, axios, safari

So I am working on a project, the frontend is on Next.JS hosted on vercel, the backend is on Express.JS hosted on heroku.

I am using express-session along with passport JS to store the sessions.

On the frontend I am using axios for the HTTP calls. The cookie for the session is being saved on Chrome, but on Safari it is not being saved. I have gone through multiple StackOverflow posts but none worked. Safari is receiving the cookie in the header but it is not saving the cookie
[image: Cookie being received on Safari]

Here is my cors configuration on express
[image: cors configuration]

What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, It turns out the reason for this happening is because Safari doesn't allow cross-domain cookies. So, the only true way to resolve this is by hosting the backend and frontend on different subdomains of the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

In cases you can't deploy them within the same domain, you can turn off the `Prevent Cross-Site Tracking` in the Safari settings (both mobile and browser) to make it work with 3rd party domain cookies.