# Django cookies not being saved in Safari nor Firefox

Tags: reactjs, django, firefox, cookies, safari

I recently started to test cookies in my development environment as I need it for token storage and csrf token. I came accross the issue of firefox and safari not setting the cookies in their storage tabs. If safari's 'prevent cross-site tracking' is off the behavior is the same with Firefox. However, not all users if any will have this setting off.
With the previous mentioned, both browsers do not save the cookies in the storage tab. But, the cookies are received as when I click in an api testing button I have after loggin in, it works and the resources are accessed since cookies are sent. But, neither Safari nor Firefox show it in the cookies tab. Here is the response after log in.

```
Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, X-CSRFToken
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Connection: close
Content-Length: 714
Content-Type: application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Tue, 18 Apr 2023 17:11:05 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: Werkzeug/2.2.3 Python/3.9.6
Set-Cookie: auth1=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9; expires=Tue, 18 Apr 2023 17:21:05 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=600; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=Y1GzI80DfRc3lMkUnboTYeA3AZBY4aih; expires=Tue, 16 Apr 2024 17:11:05 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

I am using Django and React both on localhost, but on different ports and both are running over https.
Behavior on other browsers is different as in Chrome it works fine and cookies are saved. In Edge cookies are also saved but do not persist on refresh so sort of behaves like Firefox.

Is there a way to fix this on development so I can test all browsers?

As suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311778/14659519) safari blocks cross domain cookies and so does firefox and so on. But the solution is hosting on subdomains of the same domain. How can I make this work on localhost or do I have to jump to hosting to test it?

Since I am using React the way my response is set is the following:

```
    response.set_cookie('auth1',token_header, httponly=True
, samesite='None',secure=True, max_age=600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set the cookie in the Django view that the user connects to when first visiting the site or logging in.

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect('/UserDashboard/')
response.set_cookie('user', userDB.userID)
return response
```

Modify `settings.py` by adding the following code to prevent cross-site(CSRF) cookies.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Comment: I am not suing django views but rather REST apis as I am using react on the front end. I updated the question to reflect my cookie settings. As I said chrome works fine but not Safari nor Firefox

Comment: This seems like its probably a problem with trying to set cookies using scripts on the frontend. You have a piece of code somewhere whose function is not implemented in Firefox or Safari, thats why I recommend using the backend to set cookies so as to forgo these kind of issues.

Comment: Yes, the backend is the one setting the cookies. The piece of code added is from the django rest api after I log in. And the original response is from the server which shows the cookies being sent by the server. The frontend does not touch any cookies as they are http only and can't even if I wanted to.